# How to get 1st row from repeated column values without primary key

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, scenario given below

```
sku      in_stock   sold required_stock  stock_order_on  hrs_to_arrive  hrs_to_verify   margin          
sku0001   30         30         0            2/26/2020         17.73          2.36           0.25           
sku0001   10         0          10           3/11/2020         5.91           0.79           0.25   
sku0004   20         12         13           10/12/2019        4.30           0.30           0.1
```

And Result should be like:

```
sku      in_stock   sold required_stock  stock_order_on  hrs_to_arrive  hrs_to_verify   margin          
sku0001   40         30         10           2/26/2020         17.73          2.36           0.25               
sku0004   20         12         13           10/12/2019        4.30           0.30           0.1
```

that is `SUM of in_stock, sold required_stock, stock_order_on` AND for other columns `top 1`.

I can do `top 1` query for each columns but for that I need to add `4 sub-query` or more if column list increased. 
`min(column)` also not working as columns have `int` value.
There should be a way to do it in single query, but I don't know

`Note: I need to do select query on **View** and it don't have **primary key**`

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question and include some of your own SQL attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
select t.sku, 
       sum(t.in_stock) over (partition by t.sku) as in_stock,
       sum(t.sold) over (partition by t.sku) as sold,
       sum(t.required_stock) over (partition by t.sku) as required_stock,
       t.stock_order_on t.hrs_to_arrive, t.hrs_to_verify, t.margin,
       row_number() over (partition by t.sku order by t.stock_order_on) as seq
from table t;
```

So, can filtered with `seq` :

```
select t.* 
from ( <query>
     ) t 
where seq = 1;
```